# Using Shell to analysis a file: combination of while and if

Tags: shell

I have this file like:

```
1. blah zend blahblahblahblah

2. blahblahblah blahblahblah Zend

3. Zend blahblahblahblahblahblah blah

4. Yii blahblahblahblahblahblah

5.  blahblahblahblahblahblah  Yii

6. CI blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

7. blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah CI
```

What I want is: using shell to read each line of this file, when the line contains Zend, then it will append an "a" in the end of the line, append a 'b' when the lines contains Yii  and appends a 'c' when the line contains CI.

I don't really know how to do this in one shell command,  could anyone shred a light?

I managed to do it one by one though, LIke:

```
cat test2 | while read line; do echo "$line a" | grep Zend || echo $line; done  > test
```

I suppose what I need would require a combination of "while" and "if"

Comment: How likely is it that Zend or Yii or CI will appear in the *same* line? If yes, do you want to append multiple letters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try awk; it handles situation like this in a very good manner.  A very good awk resource is [GNU Awk user's Guide.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Awk can be used in your situation as follows:

```
cat test2 | awk '{ if ( $0 ~ ".*Zend.*" ) { print $0 "a" } else if ($0 ~ ".*Yii.*") { print $0 "b" } else if ($0 ~ ".*CI.*") { print $0 "c" } else { print $0 } }'
```

Comment: -1 this answer does not print lines which do not contain any of those patterns.

Comment: Edited to correct the problem of not printing lines that don't contain the pattern.  Got -1'ed in the mean time! :(

Comment: One more tgubg RS, what if I want "Zend" or other keywords to be case insensitive, so if there is one string 'zend', there will aslo be added an '

Comment: The pattern in the quotes is regular expression.  So we could swap out .*Zend.* with .*[Zz]end.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*Zend.*$\)/\1 a/g;s/\(^.*Yii.*$\)/\1 b/g;s/\(^.*CI.*$\)/\1 c/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '// {found=0}
     /Zend/ {print $0 " a"; found=1}
     /Yii/ {print $0 " b"; found=1}
     /CI/ {print $0 " c"; found=1}
     // {if (found==0) {print $0}}'
```

I'm assuming you want a space between end of each line and `a`, `b`, or `c`. If not, you can remove it from the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do
  case $line in 
    *Zend*) suffix=" a" ;;
    *Yii*) suffix=" b" ;;
    *CI*) suffix=" c" ;;
    *) suffix="" ;;
  esac
  echo "$line$suffix"
done < filename
```

If you want case-insensitive matching and you're using bash, add `shopt -s nocasematch` first.